# The intersection of all $gA$ containing $x$,where $g\in G$ , is a block.

Tags: group-theory

Excuse me for the previous problem in my post,i have a problem with my computer  the question is:

Let $G$ transitive in $ X$, $x\in X$ and $\emptyset\neq A\subset X$. Then

$$\bigcap_{x\in gA}gA\;,\;\;g\in G$$

is a block.

Thank you for the further answers.

Comment: This is the corrección of my previous post

Comment: What definition of a block  are you familiar to? What is that?

Comment: gB = B (g fixes B) or
gB ∩ B = ∅ (g moves B entirely).

Comment: For all g in G, where B is the block

Comment: Set $B=\bigcap_{x\in A^g}A^g$.If $B=\emptyset$ or $B=X$we have nothing to do. Ok?

Comment: @user78594 , you can click on "edit" on your post and check the orders given to properly write mathematics in this site. you can also go to the FAQ section and read there direction on how to use LaTeX here.

Comment: OK, i am new in this site and i don't have any experience in LaTeX, Thank you for the help in my question.

Comment: In effect, if B is the empty set or if B=X is trivially true, but in the other cases?

Comment: Any help would be most appreciated,